# mipmap shows wrong image in android studio

Tags: android

I uploaded a few images to the android studio by clicking res->image asset so I can see the images in res->mipmap. When I'm presenting the images in an `ImageView (imvProduct.setImageResource(R.mipmap.laptop);)`, I can see only the last image I uploaded (not laptop) and I can't see the small preview sign on the left.

I noticed that in the navigation bar on the left the xml file shows in the preview the last image uploaded and the png file shows the correct one (see image). This goes to the last image.

The navigation bar on the left in the mipmap folder:

[image]

Comment: Build - Clean or File - Invalidate Caches / Restart could help here.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work... 
I can't see the small image icon in the left near the line numbers neither. Can it be connected?